# Can't resolve $http.put(); Access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

Im trying to consume a rest service developed in MVC 4 .net WEB API. I've not had any problem with $http.get() and $http.get(param). When i've tried $http.put() i get an error. Well i've lied. When I started with this simple project i had problems with the same issue to consume the get methods and I managed them in this way:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work now. This is the error angularjs console shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEgwh.jpg

(I can't put images yet so i put a link)

What should i do to be able to consume put method?

Comment: Did you enabled CORS ?

Comment: When I wrote the piece of code i've shown in the post, i wrote it because I read in a webpage that this way cors was enabled. Isn't like this? I'm new in this kind of applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled PUT in you web.config file? During development mine looks like this.

```
<system.webServer>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Also in order to enable  PUT and DELETE verbs with Web API you need to edit the applicationhost.config file which can be found at %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config and you need to add the verbs to the ExtensionlessUrl handler so you can use them:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Comment: I've done the changes in web.config and it continues raising the same error. About the applicationhost.config file, i've got no iisexpress folder in %userprofile%\documents\ path. I'm not using iis to publish the service, just playing it directly from Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I know that MS switched from Cassini to using IISExpress in VS2012. I think for VS2010, you can replace the DEV server by downloading IISExpress and enabling  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-express-support-in-vs-2010-sp1.aspx. Otherwise you'll need to work out how to enable the verbs for WebAPI in VS201 or use IIS (full). Did anyone at MS think about enabling PUT VERBS and WebApI in 2010 ???  :)

Comment: I've downloaded the IIS Express 7.5 and mounted the solution on it. It works now. Thank there!